Asymptotic expansion in the parameter $H$ for the composite midpoint rule
I am studying for an exam in numerical analysis and trying to answer the following question: Derive an asymptotic expansion in the parameter $H$ for the composite midpoint rule.
Now, I am not sure what asymptotic expansion refers to in the numerical literature, so I will assume what it means and hope that someone corrects me if I am wrong.
On an interval $[a,b]$ with a fixed $m\ge 1$, the composite midterm rule divides $[a,b]$ into $m$ intervals $[a+kH, a+(k+1)H]$, with $H=(b-a)/m$ and $0\le k\le m-1$ and approximates $I=\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ as $I_m(f)=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} f(\frac{x_k+x_{k+1}}{2})$.
To estimate the error, I will use, assuming $f\in C^\infty[a,b]$, that $f(x)-f(\frac{x_k+x_{k+1}}{2})\sim \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(\frac{x_k+x_{k+1}}{2})}{k!} (x-\frac{x_k+x_{k+1}}{2})^k$, where $\sim$ denotes "asymptotic to".
We then estimate the error as
$$
\begin{align}
E_m(f) &= \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \int_{a+kH}^{a+(k+1)H}f(x)-f(\frac{x_k+x_{k+1}}{2})dx \\
&\sim  \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \int_{x_k}^{x_{k+1}} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(\frac{x_k+x_{k+1}}{2})}{k!} (x-\frac{x_k+x_{k+1}}{2})^k \\
&=(b-a)\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{f^{(2j)}(\frac{x_k+x_{k+1}}{2})}{(2j+1)!} \frac{H^{2j}}{2^{2j}}
\end{align}
$$
Is this what the question is asking for?
This seems to align with the assumptions of Richardson extrapolation, which uses such a power series to improve the accuracy of the quadrature.
